# Returning multi SQL value as one row (despite its length) in HTML table

Tags: html, sql

This question might be seems basic but I don't know how to return multi SQL value as one row in HTML despite its length.

This is my current table looks like:
[image]

This is an example on how it looks like after filled by value.

[image]

With this code of mine:

```html
        <div class="table">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>No</th>
              <th>Location 1</th>
              <th>Location 2</th>
              <th>Location 3</th>
              <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>{{$query.No}}</td>
              <td>{{$query.Location_1}}</td>
              <td>{{$query.Location_2}}</td>
              <td>{{$query.Location_3}}</td>
              <td style="text-align: left;">{{$query.Currency} {$query.Price}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
```

What I'm trying to do is to combine $query.Currency $query.Price $... and so on as one row, without any endline.

Desired Output:

[image]

Comment: I think the problem is more to do with the place on the page and the avaliable width then ths html code of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally found out how to solve the breaking space for SQL return variables in my problem.

If you guys ever encountered such problem, you can fix it by separating variables. Here is how:

```
<td style="text-align: left;">{{$query.Currency}} {{$query.Price}}</td>
```